# Store contents of page in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing CMS in core php5, in which i am adding pages,like WordPress.

but actual Problem is that, page contents contain special characters like, single Quote(') which can not be inserted in mysql database.

I used PDO

```
http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
```

also this function

```
 $add_to_database = mysql_real_escape_string($contents)
```

but still the Problem is same, when i fetch contents on front the special characters creating Problem,

please Help me

thanks

Comment: It appears you did not really read the documentation that comes with PDO and did not study any examples about how to use PDO and "prepared statements". Using PDO the right way you do _not_ have to manually escape content using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, PDO will take care of that in a much more secure way.

Comment: can you post your insert code?? if you have not solved this issue yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base64_encode` is the Best Solution I think

```
$contents  = base64_encode($_POST['page_contents']);
```

Query will be

```
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES('".$contents ."');
```

when fetching

```
$page_contents = mysql_fetch_array($contents);

echo base64_decode($page_contents['content']);
```

Comment: Why should it be required to `base64encode()` the `$content`? Certainly you can insert arbitrary content into a mysql database without that.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 ways one is html entities and another one to use base64_encode

```
$contents  = htmlentities($_POST['page_contents']);
$contents  = base64_encode($_POST['page_contents']);
```